# Remove all trailing spaces and replace with single comma R

Tags: regex, r

I have a dataset below I need to remove all whitespace between the three text columns and replace with a single comma. I tried a few options with gsub but nothing worked. I'd like to do this in R

```
gsub("^ *|(?<= ) | *$", ",", all_data, perl=T)
```

Sample below all spacing is different sizes in the file (the number is just a row number)

```
> [1] Pig                            Piggy             2     
> [2] Chicken                        Chick            7     
> [3] Cow                               Calf     3
```

Desired output:

> Pig,Piggy,2
>
> Chicken,Chick,7
>
> Cow,Calf,3

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be better if your sample could be copy-pasted into r. Guidance here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28481250/1191259

Comment: Have you tried with `gsub("[[:blank:]]+", ",", data)`

Comment: @SabDeM I think it need `[[:blank:]]+`

Comment: to make it greedy, right @akrun thank you as always.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
gsub("\\s+", ",", gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "",x))
[1] "Pig,Piggy,2"     "Chicken,Chick,7" "Cow,Calf,3"
```

Any trailing or leading spaces will be eliminated without adding extraneous commas.

Sometimes odd character strings like this show up when the data is read into R with default settings. By using one of the many features of `?read.table` you may be able to avoid issues ahead of time. One in particular is `strip.white`. When set to `TRUE` it will eliminate the extra spaces. Then it would be an easier operation to separate with commas.

Comment: and might i recommend [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/rlanguage.html) intro to `regex`

Comment: The last space run will give a ending comma to the string. The OP's input has an trailing spaces following the last number, 2 for the fast case for example.

Comment: @Frash I was thinking the same thing, but it's not clear to me if those are real trailing spaces or just an artifact of how R chooses to print results.

Comment: @Frank Based on the OP's code ` *$` looks like he has trailing spaces

Answer (score 3):

As my previous comment (thank to Akrun for suggestions):

```
gsub("[[:blank:]]+", ",", x)
[1] "Pig,Piggy,2"     "Chicken,Chick,7" "Cow,Calf,3"
```

data:

```
c("Pig                            Piggy             2", "Chicken                        Chick            7", 
"Cow                               Calf     3")
```

Comment: This looks the same as Pierre's answer. I suppose one could also write the regex as `" +"` and a few other ways...

Comment: @Frank my solution is with POSIX Character Classes, Pierre's one is with standard regex's "Character shorthands", just another point of view of the same thing I guess.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably take the long way around instead of using pure regex:

```
sapply(strsplit(s," +"), paste0, collapse=",")
# [1] "Pig,Piggy,2"     "Chicken,Chick,7" "Cow,Calf,3"
```

Or, as Pierre mentioned, read the data in correctly from the get-go.

---

**Data:**

```
s = c("Pig                            Piggy             2     ",
      "Chicken                        Chick            7     ",
      "Cow                               Calf     3")
```